# Separate a relationship from the collection on Laravel 8 - Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I am generating a query that collects an invoice, and the related invoice customer.

```
$invoice = Invoice::with(['lines', 'fullClient'])->findOrFail($idInvoice);     
return view('invoiceView', ['invoice'=>$invoice]);
```

It works correctly, through $invoice->clients, I can access the client.
But I would like to be able to separate the client from the collection invoice. To send it through another variable. So that it looks something like this:

```
$invoice = Invoice::with(['lines', 'fullClient'])->findOrFail($idInvoice); 
//Some magic here
return view('invoiceView', ['invoice'=>$invoice,'client'=>$client]);
```

It is to take advantage of an invoice creation view (to be able to edit), which is expected by the $clients collection.
I have searched, to do this in the view, but it is not possible or it is not recommended.

I guess I could do something like thisbefore sending it to view:

```
$client = $invoice->customer
```

But then I would be sending it twice on view.

Comment: You keep saying `collection` but I don't see any (?) Are you refering to model?

Comment: I am new with Laravel. I think I read in some place, that all eloquent queries return a collection.

Comment: It depends. `find(1)`, `findOrFail(1)`, `first()`, ... will return a `Model` but `get()`, `findMany([1, 2])`, `find([1, 2])`... will return a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) which contains an array of Models. A collection is just a wrapper around an array and provide [fluent methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unset the relationship from a model you can use [`unsetRelation($relation)`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L809) method

```php
$invoice = Invoice::with(['lines', 'fullClient'])->findOrFail($idInvoice); 
$client = $invoice->fullClient;

$invoice->unsetRelation('fullClient');

return view('invoiceView', ['invoice'=>$invoice,'client'=>$client]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use `pluck()`

```
$invoice = Invoice::with(['lines', 'fullClient'])->findOrFail($idInvoice); 
//The magic
$client = $invoice->pluck('fullClient');
return view('invoiceView', ['invoice'=>$invoice,'client'=>$client]);
```

[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck)

Comment: AFAIK `pluck()` does not unset the relation from `$invoice`